# How to make .htaccess to ignore /#/ or /!#/ in url

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, url

I have portfolio page where I use AJAX to switch between pages, my url looks like this when you are in portoflio and some work:

.../portfolio/#/work-1

but when I copy paste the full link into browser ( i am thinking of if someone copy paste link to show someone the work ) he gets to .../portfolio page and not to page with the work he wanted, seems like it ignore everything after the #, can i make .htaccess rule to igrone for example /# in urls ?

Answer (score 0):

No, since the server never sees that part in the first place. You will need to use JavaScript on the `portfolio/` page to deal with that.

Comment: You mean like, if ( hash.contains(prefix) ) { takeHash.removePrefix.gotoResultUrl } ?